# How to import SVG files?

Tags: import, svg-format

In the document I found that SVG files can be exported, but there is no information of Import.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: If you look at the documentation (I am using MMA 12) SVG is not listed as a format that can be imported. You can check which file formats are supported by using the command `$ImportFormats`

Comment: @Dunlop Thank you for your advice. I just want to know how can I do it, it's not limited to be done with Import. I didn't found any related information on this forum, so I think maybe I have to use some external programs to do this. Or I may need to learn something about svg and do it by myself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not currently supported by the built-in functions, but there is a function called `SVGImport` in the function repository that can do this:
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SVGImport

Comment: Thank you. I've forgotten this site. I knew this website just yesterday.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative answer: Use the SVG importer from my [Prototypes paclet](https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/prototypes):

https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/prototypes/releases/tag/0.5.6

To install the paclet, run this command:

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/prototypes/releases/download/v0.5.6/Prototypes-0.5.6.paclet"]
```

Note that this paclet has many many functions, but you may be able to extract just the SVG importer if that's all you need.

After that you can load the package:

```
Get["Prototypes`"]
```

Normally this package autoloads when you use a function from the package, but not in this case which uses `Import`.

Next run `Import` to import the SVG file ([example source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Hubei_in_China_%28%2Ball_claims_hatched%29.svg)):

```
Import["D:\\tmp\\in.svg", "SVG"]
```

[image]

**Important note:** This implementation uses the [Apache-Batik java library](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) and imports the SVG as a raster image and not as a graphics object. So you lose the scalability of the SVG. On the other hand, this implementation does a very faithful rendering of SVG file (exceeding, in certain cases, the result from the SVGImport resource function (which works well in a lot of cases too).

Comment: When is SVG support coming by default in WL? 12.3? 13.0? Are you guys working on it?

Comment: Not sure yet when this will be in WL, because fully supporting it is complex. There is now also this WFR entry though: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SVGImport/

Comment: Wait, does this mean that Java has to be present for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your usage scenario, converting the SVG files to PDF via [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) and then importing the PDF files using the regular Mathematica Import[] function might be a viable alternative.

I tried this with Inkscape 0.92 and Mathematica 12 on Linux, albeit only for one file.

Inkscape can also do the conversion from SVG to PDF using command line options. Therefore, if you have many files, you could automatize the conversion process.