# Importing SVG files

Tags: import

I would like to import a bunch of SVG files to my notebook.
In my attempt to do so, I have used

```
ResourceFunction["SVGImport"][svgfile];
```

where "svgfile" contains the path to my SVG file.
This line of script gives the following error
[image]

I have generated my SVG file from [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecsk/hat/app.html) with keeping "Draw Supertiles" off.
I have also tried some of the suggestions in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212486/how-to-import-svg-files), but the issue persists.
Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have python configured to work in Mathematica? This is a requirement for `SVGImport` to work. Check if `ExternalEvaluate["Python", "1+1"]` works. Otherwise, I can import the tiles [without a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX636.png).

Comment: I see! The output of `ExternalEvaluate["Python", "1+1"]` is `2` on my systems. So I assume it works. Do you know how I can check whether the Python configurations are all set?